# Which AID does Apple Pay respond to?

Tags: arduino, nfc, iso, applepay

I'm playing a bit with an iPhone6 and my Arduino with NFC board.
I need to know the ISO7816 Application Identifier to send in the SELECT AID command. I'm trying some well known AIDs, Apple Pay show up perfectly, I use TouchID to authorise the payment, but then the iPhone NFC controller replies with 6A 82 (File Not Found).
I have configured a MasterCard Debit card in PassBook.
Thanks!
Roberto

Comment: I've tested A0000000041010 (official MasterCard AID) and now the SELECT AID command simply fails. Maybe this is the AID I wanted?

Comment: Hola Roberto, have you found any solution about it? I'm also interested

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an iOS driver for a payment terminal that accepts ApplePay. VISA cards return AID A00000000031010 whereas MasterCard AID A0000000041010. I hope this helps you. I can try Amex and Discover later if you want.